# Trigger camera shutter on iPhone from Macbook

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, remote-control, switchcontrol

I'm writing a script on my macbook to trigger the camera shutter on my iPhone.

I'm struggling to understand how to do this programmatically. I've tried:

- Using macbook as bluetooth keyboard (don't know how to simulate a volume press)
- Using "Switch Control" functionality on Macbook to control the iPhone device (unfortunately it seems like the simulated keypresses don't get sent over to the iPhone)

Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: DO you want the application to be submitted to App store? or you are trying it for your personal thing?

Comment: I'm using it for personal use

Answer (score 0):

You're close! While a bit of a kluge, you can connect a Bluetooth keyboard to your phone, enable Switch Control on iOS, and bind a key to the "Increase Volume" action. If that doesn't work, you can always bind keys to the "Move to Next Item" and "Select Item" actions, and then then move through the interface one element at a time until you reach the shutter button.